# An invariant number of modules over Auslander Gorenstein modules

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Given an Auslander Gorenstein $R$ of injective dimension $\mu$, one can associate with each finitely generated module $M$ with a number $\varepsilon_{\mu}(M)$, which is the number of the $\mu$-critical factors in a critical composition of $M$. It is known that $\varepsilon_\mu$ is additive, that means $\varepsilon_\mu(M)=\varepsilon_\mu(L)+\varepsilon_\mu(N)$ for any short exact sequence $0\to L\to M\to N\to 0$ of finitely generated modules. However I am stucked with this fact. Any comments will be grateful.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you are asking. Does being $\mu$-critical mean that $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M,R)\neq 0$ (ie canonical dimension $\mu$) but for every proper quotient $M/N$ of $M$, $\mathrm{Hom}_R(M/N,R)\neq 0$? In any case this paper http://www.math.washington.edu/~smith/Research/asz6.pdf of Ajitabh, Smith and Zhang is likely to be useful.

Comment: If my interpretation above is correct then I think you are asking about the quotient category $\mathcal{M}^\mu$ in the notation of that paper.